# Creating Two-Column Affiliation List in \maketitle Environment

Tags: tables, titles, two-column, affiliation, author-number

I'm new to LaTeX and I have searched for an answer to my question to no avail.  I am trying to create an affiliation list that allows me to squeeze more affiliations onto the page by use of a two-column table instead of everything being center-aligned with each new affiliation taking up a new line.  This is my document:

```
\documentclass [english, 12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{4pt}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
  \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Large\bfseries\@title}
    {\normalsize
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}
    {\large \@date}
  \end{center}%
}
\makeatother
\date{} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{Vincent}
\author[2]{John Doe}
\affil[1]{Overleaf Inc.}
\affil[2]{Overleaf Pro Inc.}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the two affiliations as a two-column table, but I'm unsure how to do this in my current environment.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular` won't work correctly here as the package `authblk` redefines is to `center`.

I would suggest to use the `multicols` environment from the package `multicol` to get the affiliations in two columns. This requires you to redefine `@author`.

By the way, if you keep the `\author` and `\affil` commands together, there is no need to give the numbers explicitely, as the package will auto-number them.

So here is my solution.

```
\documentclass [english, 12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{4pt}
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{99}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@author{
    \AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{quotation}
        \AB@affillist
      \end{quotation}
    \end{multicols}
    }
\def\@maketitle{
  \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Large\bfseries\@title}
    {\normalsize
      \begin{center}%
        \baselineskip=12pt
        \@author
      \end{center}\par}
    {\large \@date}
  \end{center}%
}
\makeatother
\date{} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Vincent}
\affil{Overleaf Inc.}
\author{John Doe}
\affil{Overleaf Pro Inc.}
\author{Mary Doe}
\affil{Underleaf Inc.}
\author{Peter}
\affil{Underleaf Pro Inc.}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would I then change the multicol so that there are no margins on the side of the page (besides the 1 in global margin)?  I'm getting some text wrapping on some of my affiliations.  Also, the reason I have them numbered is that the authors have multiple affiliations and are not in order according to affiliation so I need them to be specified.

Comment: Remove the `\begin{quotation}` and `\end{quotation}`.  These I added to indent the list on both sides, which looked nicer to me.